# libSDL not recognized in installer

Tags: apt, software-installation, configure

I'm trying to install Rejoystick for my system (Latest version of GalliumOS), and when I run ./configure (What README says to do) it spits out the error that I don't have libSDL. But running

```
sudo apt install libSDL2-2.0-0
```

Just says libSDL2.2-0.0 is already installed. And when i try to install the libSDL2-dev package the same thing happens. Why does the installer not recognize libSDL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `./configure` script is looking for SDL version 1, not SDL version 2. You’ll have to install the SDL 1 development package.